# Redirect to previous page after registration in Django

Tags: django, redirect, registration, create-view

For login and logout, I use Django's built-in view in django.contrib.auth.views. It is very easy to redirect user to previous page because you can pass a 'next' parameter to the login/logout view. They work quit fine.

When I want to fulfill the similar functionality for Registration, there are some problems. It seems that Django doesn't have a built-in registration view. So I'm using the CreateView with 'model=User'. Codes are following:

```
#views.py

class Registration(CreateView):
    template_name='accounts/registration.html'
    model=User

    #Overwrite form_valid() to log this new user in after his successful registartion
    def form_valid(self, form):
        validation=super(Registration, self).form_valid(form)

        username=form.cleaned_data['username']
        password=form.cleaned_data['password2']
        user=authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        login(self.request, user)

        return validation
```

Now I don't have a similar 'next' parameter as in the built-in login/logout view. Then how can I redirect the new user to previous page after registration?

I tried the following method:

**Step1:** 
From the template which will trigger my Registration view, pass a 'next' parameter via GET method.

```
<a href="{% url 'accounts:Registration' %}?next={{request.path}}">Registration</a>
```

By the way, the url related to registration is:

```
#accounts/urls.py

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Others
    url(r'^registration/$', views.Registration.as_view(), name='registration'),
)
```

**Step2:** 
Overwrite the get_context_data() and get_success_url() methods, trying to construct my own 'next' parameter:

```
#views.py

    class Registration(CreateView):

        # other codes as above

        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
              context=super(Registration, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
              context[next]=self.request.GET['next']
              return context

        def get_success_url(self):
              redirect_to=self.request.POST['next']
              return redirect_to
```

**Step3:** 
In my template, add a 'hidden' input field to hold the next value:

```
# accounts/registration.html

<form method="post" action="{% url 'accounts:registration' %}" > {% csrf_token %}
    <p>
    {{form.as_p}}
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Regsitarte" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value={{next}} /> 
</form>
```

This method only works fine when the user doesn't make  any mistake during his registration procedure. If, for example, the user POSTs a username which is existing, or the format of the email address is invalid, this method will report an error about the "next" parameter.

Can anyone give a method to redirect a user after registration? Or Can you alter my codes to fulfill this functionality? I'd like to use Django's Built-in Class-based Generic Views, instead of write a new view from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you leave a HTML forms `action` attribute blank it defaults to the URL of the current page, *`GET` query parameters and all*.

If you change your form to remove the hidden field and remove the action it should work fine:

```
<form method="post">
    <p>
    {{form.as_p}}
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Regsitarte" /> 
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! Actually, I'm using JQuery's .load() method to load my registration.html into  any page the user now is seeing. So if I leave 'action' blank, it can't find the right url as the current page may not be the registration page. But you give me some inspiration. I change the 'action' to `<form method="post" action="{% url 'accounts:registration' %}?next={{next}}" >`. Then it solves my problem. Thank you a lot!